# (Iphone) Retrieve Id from a Cell and use it in another query to display entry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

I have a TableView who display the name of some Categories by executing this simple query

```
 
"select * from category" so my object contain id_category and name.
```

When I click on a row, a new tableView will display somes names inside thoses different categories.

```
"Select * from fiche_Category where id_category = ?"
```

My only problem is I don't know how to retrieve the id_category from every cell and insert it inside my **?** on my second query.

I just want to be able to display the fiche_category from the category I choose.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another solution,
In my file ressource Manager I create a function to take a int as an argument:

```
- (void)getFichesCategory:(int)value { 
...
sqlite3_bind_int(getFichesCategoryStatement, 1,  value);
...
}
```

After that inside my View controller, I use the ViewWillAppear and I call my function where I retrieve the id_category from my 1st query [self.categories idModuleCategory] intValue] :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.title = self.categories.title;

    RessourceManager *appDelegate = [RessourceManager  sharedResources];
    [appDelegate getFichesCategory:[[self.categories idModuleCategory] intValue] ];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, you can find the index of the cell you clicked by using:

```
int index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
```

with this index you can go through the result you retrieved from your first sql statement and find the record you clicked and with that the id_category.

Comment: thanks that will maybe help me for later.. but what is the -1 ??

Comment: if you have an array with length n then the index of the last element is n-1